# python web scraping with beautifulsoup find <li> in different <ul> name tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<ul id="name1">
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
 </ul>
<ul id="name2">
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
 </ul>
```

Hi. I scraping something website. There are different numbers of li tags in different ul tag names. I think there is something wrong with my method. I want your help.

NOTE:
The bottom part of the code is the code of the image I took from the site

```
    ts1 = brosursoup.find("div", attrs={"id": "name"})
    ts2 = ts1.find("ul")

    hesap = 0

    count2 = len(ts1.find_all('ul'))

    if (hesap <= count2):
        hesap = hesap + 1
        for qwe in ts1.find_all("ul", attrs={"id": f"name{hesap}"}):
            for bnm in ts1.find_all("li"):
                for klo in ts1.find_all("div"):
                    tgf = ts1.find("span", attrs={"class": "img_w_v8"})
                    for abn in tgf.find_all("img"):
                        picture = abn.get("src")
                        picturename= abn.get("title")
                        print(picture + " ------ " + picturename)
```

Comment: Do you want all the `li` tags or do you want only the `li` tags under a specific `ul` tag?

Comment: If you are looking for `li` inside `qwe` then you probably need `for bnm in qwe.find_all("li"):`, similarly for the `div`

Comment: @Ananth yes, I want only the li tags under a specific ul tag

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to include suitable HTML which would work with your script? And show what the desired output would be

Comment: @MartinEvans output is only li tags in name1 ul tag

Answer (score 1):

You can just find which `ul` tag you want and then use `find_all`.

```
page = '<ul id="name1">
            <li>li1</li>
            <li>li2</li>
            <li>li3</li>
            <li>li4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="name2">
             <li>li5</li>
             <li>li6</li>
             <li>li7</li>
         </ul>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
ul_tag = soup.find('ul', {'id': 'name2'})
li_tags = ul_tag.find_all('li')
for i in li_tags:
    print(i.text)

# output

li5
li6
li7
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to match all `ul` elements of the form `id='nameXXX'` then you can use a regular expression as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = '''<ul id="name1">
            <li>li1</li>
            <li>li2</li>
            <li>li3</li>
            <li>li4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="name2">
             <li>li5</li>
             <li>li6</li>
             <li>li7</li>
         </ul>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

for ul in soup.find_all('ul', {'id': re.compile('name\d+')}):
    for li in ul.find_all('li'):
        print(li.text)
```

This would display:

```
li1
li2
li3
li4
li5
li6
li7
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """<ul id="name1">
            <li>li1</li>
            <li>li2</li>
            <li>li3</li>
            <li>li4</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="name2">
             <li>li5</li>
             <li>li6</li>
             <li>li7</li>
         </ul>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
ul_tag = soup.find_all('ul', {"id": ["name1", "name2"]})

for i in ul_tag:
    print(i.text)
```